# hundreds of checkboxes on a form make IE8 respond slowly

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

We're trying to show checkboxes for the 700+/- options that the user has.  It's to map users to accounts, for all intents and purposes.

The checkboxes start runing extremely slow under Internet Explorer 8.  Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc. run like a champ without issue.

Does anyone have a better, faster, and cleaner method (other than checkboxes) to utilize for this?

Comment: 700 checkboxes! wow... any way is better!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wound up going back to the users and showing them the fact that the page rendered like crap, and ultimately, they said "That's not a problem"!  So, we're stuck with the 2,100+/- controls :/

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. Use a select control. Consider using two select controls, and copying the selected values from one control to the other. This is more usable than a large multi-select.
2. Split your form into multiple, smaller pages.
3. Allow the user to complete a portion of the form, and load the additional parts via AJAX as needed.

Comment: 1 -> that's how it is enabled currently, but when you're highlighting 700+/- items, or even moving 700+/- items over into a second control, it gets rather cumbersome to validate what you assign where.#2... may think about it #3... ajax is slow on IE8.  We were implementing with that, only to have to revert most, if not all of it.

Comment: If I may say so, IE8 is not really the problem here. The problem may manifest more in that browser, but a 700+ field form is indicative of a design flaw. Even the better browsers will experience some slowness with such a form.

Comment: Strange... All of the other modern browsers I tried (opera, firefox, safari) all worked without flaw.  jQuery .Button() added an additional level of overhead.  I think it's just IE can't handle 2,100+ controls on the page.

Comment: As I was telling @Daok, the userbase wants a thick-client application within a web-application, and can't understand why you can't give 'em everything.  In business applications like this, it's normal to have this large of a set of data... Honestly, I'm not entirely against their comments on this, to be honest.  I don't feel like 700 items should be that bad to handle, although it is.

Comment: 2100+?? Mamma mia! Think of the children! Does anyone ever complete that monster?

Comment: As web professionals, it is part of our job to educate our clients. If they want a form with 2100+ controls, you need to stand up to them and tell them it won't work properly. It is bad for users. It is bad for performance. It is error prone. What if the user accidentally hits the Back button when he is 92% done? This type of user interface should never be condoned. There are better solutions.

Comment: Asp.Net MVC3, to create a checkbox with a label creates 3 controls... a hidden form field, an input for the checkbox, and the label itself.  Seriously thinking of writing a quick & dirty Silverlight app to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have a better, faster, and cleaner method (other than checkboxes) to utilize for this?

I think you should Page your data in a table with multiple page. 700 checkboxes is a UI-Smell from my point of view.

Comment: Paging felt rather slow and unresponsive as well.  Again, it's an IE-only issue... Firefox, Mozilla, et al seemed to be OK with things.

Comment: Even if it works for Mozilla Firefox it's not a good way to represent data to the user. Can I see a screenshot of how it looks, I am curious.

Comment: imagine a select box for selecting a user, with a table that has an employee name and a checkbox next to them inside of a table.  That is all the page shows at this point.

Comment: Maybe you should just load the list of user. If the list is over a threshold (you decide) you let the user have an autocomplete field or a kind of filter. When a choice is done, you do an Ajax call to the server to get the data for you CheckBoxes. This way, you do not load all data for nothing.

Comment: It's an IT application... I'm always going to have this list of 700+ items to be worked with.  Thinking of showing a grid with a delete link for those that are assigned, and then show a listbox that they can highlight those they want to add to the permission, and give 'em an "Add" button.

Comment: My issue is still that the user wants what they want, and there's no way of really giving it to them on a web-based application.

Answer (score 0):

Even if is feasible in the other browsers, from the point of view of user friendliness it would be a nightmare.

One possible solution:

1.- Instead of checkboxes use to select lists, in the left one put all the available one, in the right the ones selected

2.- Categorize and/or divide in multiple steps

3.- Add a addAll and removeAll buttons for each page/category

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use 10 user controls with jQuery in it and render all the controls at pipe line. This way its not too much load at the server side and your controls will be async with each other.

Just my cents on it..

Comment: The slowdown he is experiencing in IE8 is not likely to be a server-side issue. The page is rendered slowly because it contains too many input elements. Rendering those same elements via jQuery would add another layer of computation, thus slowing down the process even more.